# Creating many objects from JSON using JACKSON

Tags: android, json, jackson

I need to parse a pretty big json in my Android app, and from what I've read online, Jackson is what I need.

From what I can see, i don't think that i have errors in how i use jackson, but still something goes wrong when i try to create objects...Maybe i run out of memory...or IDK.

My jackson code :

```
    public void renderProducts(String url, JSONArray ja, AjaxStatus status) throws JSONException, JsonParseException, IOException {

        if(ja == null) return;

        ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();

        // new code

        JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonParser jParser = jfactory.createJsonParser(ja.toString());

        // loop until token equal to "]"
        while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            String fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
            String name = null;
            if ("name".equals(fieldname)) {

              // current token is "name",
               // move to next, which is "name"'s value
              jParser.nextToken();
              name = jParser.getText(); // display mkyong
              System.out.println(name);

            }
            fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
            String description = null;
            if ("description".equals(fieldname)) {

              // current token is "name",
               // move to next, which is "name"'s value
              jParser.nextToken();
              description = jParser.getText(); // display mkyong
              System.out.println(description);
            }

            fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
            String sizes [] = null;
            if ("sizes".equals(fieldname)) {

              // current token is "name",
               // move to next, which is "name"'s value
              jParser.nextToken();
              sizes = jParser.getText().split("##"); // display mkyong
              System.out.println(sizes.toString());
            }

            String prices [] = null;

            fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
            if ("prices".equals(fieldname)) {

              // current token is "name",
               // move to next, which is "name"'s value
              jParser.nextToken();
              prices = jParser.getText().split("##"); // display mkyong
              System.out.println(prices.toString());
            }
            fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
            String picUrl = null;
            if ("pic_url".equals(fieldname)) {

              // current token is "name",
               // move to next, which is "name"'s value
              jParser.nextToken();
              picUrl = jParser.getText(); // display mkyong
              System.out.println(picUrl);
            }
            fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
            String bigPicURL = null;
            if ("big_pic_url".equals(fieldname)) {

              // current token is "name",
               // move to next, which is "name"'s value
              jParser.nextToken();
              bigPicURL = jParser.getText(); // display mkyong
              System.out.println(bigPicURL);
            }
            Product p = new Product(name, sizes.toString(), description, prices.toString(),picUrl,bigPicURL,"");
            list.add(p);
            p = null;
}
```

If i comment out the last 3 lines (so i don't create my list of Product objects), then the code works...so basically it displays in the console the correct information from the json..however, if i let the last 3 lines in i get the following errors :

```
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389): reporting:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at com.androidquery.util.AQUtility.invokeMethod(AQUtility.java:200)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at com.androidquery.util.AQUtility.invokeHandler(AQUtility.java:177)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.callback(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:496)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.afterWork(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:1261)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.run(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:986)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     at com.testehan.feedme.Activity.Main.renderProducts(Main.java:322)
07-07 13:48:12.514: W/AQuery(1389):     ... 16 more
```

where line 322 is :

```
Product p = new Product(name, sizes.toString(), description, prices.toString(),picUrl,bigPicURL,"");
```

Any ideas of how i can handle this problem ? Or where is my mistake in the jackson approach?

Thanks

UPDATE: The code i use is from http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/. If i try his code and a file, it works as expected..however if a get the json from the internet..then problems appear..

Maybe because the order of key:value pairs changes?

Comment: It says _NullPointerException_, and from the code it looks like you are creating a _Product_ instance each time the while loop executes. However, your _Product_ takes both _sizes.toString()_ and _prices.toString()_, which by the nature of your code at least one of them will be null, making that line always throwing a _NullPointerException_.

Comment: @Kai the lines that populate them are `sizes = jParser.getText().split("##"); // display mkyong` and `prices = jParser.getText().split("##");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org), opting, instead for [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), which [has JSON support](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html):

```
    Product product = new Product("Banana", "123", 23.00);
    com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream xstream = new XStream(new com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
    xstream.setMode(com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
    xstream.alias("product", Product.class);

    System.out.println(xstream.toXML(product));
```

The code above gives:

```
{"product":{"name":"Banana","id":123,"price":23.0}}
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.

The linked page has code to do the reverse, as well, but:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver;
    // crap here
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
    xstream.alias("product", Product.class);
    Product product = (Product)xstream.fromXML(json);
```

Also note, XStream handles collections transparently, both with JSON and XML.

Comment: i need the exactly opposite...so from json to object :). I have an array of  json objects that needs to become an array of java products

Comment: I will try to use this, and come back later to confirm if it worked